# can't understand a macro definition (casting constant number to a class pointer)

Tags: c++, macros

in a code, I see a macro defined below that I can't understand.

```
#define OFFSET_OF_FIELD_(f) (reinterpret_cast<char*>(      \
  &reinterpret_cast<NetParameter*>(16)->f) - \
   reinterpret_cast<char*>(16))
```

The macro name seems to be calculating the offset of a field f inside the class structure. and it has the form of subtracting the start address from the address of a field. How is number 16 used here? and deosn't reinterpret_case apply only to 16?(not 16 -> f). 
I would appreciate if somebody please explain this code to me.

Comment: It seems to be "imagining" a `NetParameter` object at a generic address 16 just to calculate the offset of the `f` field. I would totally advice against this sort of hacks.

Comment: @MarcoA. but why 16?  why not 0.  Also this sort of "hack" is perfectly legal in certain circumstances.   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof

Comment: @xaxxon my question as well. I guess not 0 to avoid null-pointer issues, but then why not 8 or 32?

Comment: Prefer to use old standard (POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008, C89, C99) the offsetof marco instead of OFFSET_OF_FIELD_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment in a (now refactored) protobuf header (link [here](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h?q=GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_GENERATED_MESSAGE_FIELD_OFFSET&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=599)) explains it

```
// Note that we calculate relative to the pointer value 16 here since if we
// just use zero, GCC complains about dereferencing a NULL pointer.  We
// choose 16 rather than some other number just in case the compiler would
// be confused by an unaligned pointer.
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_GENERATED_MESSAGE_FIELD_OFFSET(TYPE, FIELD)    \
  static_cast<int>(                                           \
      reinterpret_cast<const char*>(                          \
          &reinterpret_cast<const TYPE*>(16)->FIELD) -        \
      reinterpret_cast<const char*>(16))
#endif
```

so the reason why 16 was being used is twofold:

- Avoid using a NULL pointer
- Use an aligned pointer

Be aware that this is [known to create some issues](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/1450) (might be replaced by `__builtin_offsetof` where supported).

Comment: Oh, I see, In fact, I missed that the second reinterpret_cast  applies only to (16). now it's clear. Thanks!